# Uninstalling php 5.3 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, php

I have installed php 5.3 manually by executing commands like make & make install. But I need to upgrade it to v5.5 therefore I deleted all the directories related to php5 using sudo command.

But when I run`php -v`
Still I am getting

```
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Jun  8 2015 05:53:32) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Please help me to remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninstall something you installed from source, you would use cd back into the directory you built it from and then run `sudo make uninstall` but I don't think this will work with PHP since it doesn't have an uninstall.

So what you can do is to make a  package from the existing compiled version you have and then you could install the new created package over the old one, and if this works you can remove it. First install checkinstall if you dont have it:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Then run:

```
cd php-5.3.29
sudo checkinstall
```

Accept all the defaults.The result will be a phpXX.deb package, so try to install it, this will replace the old files from the compiled package:

```
sudo dpkg -i phpXX.deb
```

If this goes smooth then you are near to have it. Now purge the package:

```
sudo apt-get purge phpXX.deb
```

#### What to do if this doesn't work

you should remove all files manually

```
locate php5
```

Then remove the files and install a new version with `apt-get` again