# Remove php 5.3 from my system

Tags: php, php7

Previously I have both PHP 5.6 and PHP7 installed in my pc and switch between them every time I need for a web-app with:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php[version]
```

But I made the error to install 5.3 because I one app I wanted to test was running with that PHP.

But now, no matter what I do, everytime I run `php -v` I always get:

```
PHP 5.3.29 (cli)
```

I don't know where it's installed, I tried with locate php5.3 but I don't get anything (?) and with locate php5 I get all my installations from 5.6 and 7 that I want to activate.

[Uninstalling php 5.3 in ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633628/uninstalling-php-5-3-in-ubuntu-14-04)

I tried with php --ini to get a clue where is located but then:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
In /usr/local/lib there's nothing about php (?)

Any help with this?

Comment: try to `find / -name *php*`. This way you will be able to find all the PHP versions.  For the future I would recommend to run stuff with update alternatives in a docker container/virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it was only named as "php", so I couldn' track it down with the version number.

Then it was simply as

```
sudo apt-get purge php
```